# MongoDB/mongoose embedded schema vs object ID efficiency, when data in embedded/referenced schema is not always needed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a few problems conceptually understanding the best way to use MongoDB.

`B` is an embedded schema in `A` as follows.

```
var B = new Schema({});

var A = new Schema({
  aProp1 = {},
  aProp2 = {},
  bList = [B]
});
```

There are two scenarios. I either need to read `aProp1` and `aProp2`, or add a new B model and update `aProp1` and `aProp2` based on the `B` model.

It doesn't seem correct to retrieve the `bList` each time I need to read `A`. This is getting a lot of extra data on each query.

However the alternative would be storing the mongoose schema ObjectId of `B` in a list in `A`. This seems like an anti-pattern based on what I've read. To update `A` when a new `B` is added I would now need two separate queries. If `A` fails after creating a new `B` then I would have to revert `B` and this sounds like a rollback/transaction nightmare.

What is the best way to reference another schema in MongoDB when the data is not always needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `bList` is an array of references to `B`s then you could query your database without having to load everything from the `B` schema each time. You could still get the information for each `B` in your `bList` but you would use a populate when you wanted to do so.

Your `A` schema would then look like this:

```
var A = new Schema({
  aProp1 = {},
  aProp2 = {},
  bList = [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'B'}]
});
```

Then whenever you wanted to query `A` and include all of the information for each `B` in each `A` you would use [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

```
A
 .find({})
 .populate('bList')
 .exec((err, As) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(As);
 }
```